# How to read a range of bytes from a bytearray in c#

Tags: c#

I have to read a range of bytes from a byte array. I have the starting position and the ending position to read.

```
-(NSData *) getSubDataFrom:(int)stPos To:(int)endPos withData:(NSData *) data{
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(stPos, endPos);
    return [data subDataWithRage:range];
}
```

The above code in ObjectiveC reads the range of data(bytes) from a NSData(byteArray). Is there any equivelent method in c# to do the same. or how else we can do this. Please advise!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What do you mean by read? Copy a range of bytes into another byte array?

```
var mainArray = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };
var startPos = 5;
var endPos = 10;
var subset = new byte[endPos - startPos + 1];
Array.Copy(mainArray, startPos, subset, 0, endPos - startPos + 1);
```

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Array.Copy()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.array.copy.aspx)  or Array.CopyTo() method.